# PHP DOMDocument not loading

Tags: php

Even though my phpinfo() shows my DOM as enabled, when I try to call it I get an error that the class was not found.  I have tried this both on MAMP and on our IIS server and the same thing happens.  We are running 5.2+ versions of PHP.  Anyone have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Show your code, and show your exact error (copy paste please, don't re-type)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `DOM` class, it's `DomDocument`.